# Installing Armadillo with Homebrew on Mac Mavericks

Tags: c++, macos, installation, homebrew, armadillo

I have installed Armadillo with Homebrew with

```
brew install homebrew/science/armadillo
```

I have tried to compile some code with

```
g++-4.7 -I/usr/local/include file1.cpp -O2 -llapack -lblas
```

but all I get is

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_wrapper_ddot_", referenced from:
void arma::syrk<false, false, false>::apply_blas_type<double, arma::Mat<double> >(arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Mat<double> const&, double, double) in ccYKNLEL.o   "_wrapper_dgemm_", referenced from:
_main in ccYKNLEL.o   "_wrapper_dgemv_", referenced from:
_main in ccYKNLEL.o   "_wrapper_dsyrk_", referenced from:
void arma::syrk<false, false, false>::apply_blas_type<double, arma::Mat<double> >(arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Mat<double> const&, double, double) in ccYKNLEL.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture
x86_64 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and the same for

```
g++-4.7 -I/usr/local/include file1.cpp -O2 -framework accelerate
```

also including -larmadillo

```
g++-4.7 -I/usr/local/include file1.cpp -O2 -larmadillo -llapack -lblas
```

it returns

```
library not found for -larmadillo
```

And in

```
/usr/local/Cellar/armadillo/4.100.2/lib/
```

I find the libraries like `libarmadillo.4.10.2.dylib` but they can't be included with `-I`

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add `-larmadillo` to the compile command. This should work:

```
g++-4.7 -I/usr/local/include file1.cpp -O2 -larmadillo -llapack -lblas
```

Note that this is all explained in the `README.txt` file that comes with Armadillo.

Most open source software does come with README files or other documentation, and it's generally a good idea to read the documentation before using the software.

Answer (score 1):

Library can be included using `-L`

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib file1.cpp -O2 -llapack -lblas -larmadillo
```